# defaultValue returned as empty string for Custom Preference class used in Preference XML

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, dialog-preference

I am trying to create a time selection preference by extending the `DialogPreference`. I have specified a `android:defaultValue` in the Preference XML. Everything works well, but when I try to read the value of the preference from code, **I get an empty string**. Ideally, if the preference is not set, I should get the value as **5:00** which is mentioned as`android:defaultValue` in the Preference XML.

> When I retrieve the preference, how can I get the value specified as `android:defaultValue` in the
>   Preference XML, if user has not yet set the preference?

```
<com.sample.package.TimeDialogPreference
        android:defaultValue="5:00"
        android:key="@string/pref_key_time"
        android:title="@string/pref_title_time"
        android:summary="@string/pref_summary_time"
        android:dialogLayout="@layout/preference_time"
    />
```

Comment: Is the namespace correct?

Comment: @Xenolion Yes. I have changed it for posting the question. Its a custom class I have written in the app.